# Bitmap to large error is complaining about twice the image size

Tags: java, android, opengl-es, bitmap

I'm receiving the infamous `OpenGLRenderer` error that `"Bitmap too large to be uploaded into a texture."`  I'm familiar with the error and know that I need to keep my images below `2048 pixels` to avoid it.

However, on one particular phone, the Samsung Galaxy Nexus, it is reporting image sizes that are twice the actual image size.

My image is in the `drawable` folder and has a size of `2048x95`.  When I run the app and attempt to add that image to the display, I get the infamous error:

> Bitmap too large to be uploaded into a texture (4096x190, max=2048x2048)

What gives?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your image is in the drawable folder then it will be scaled to the appropriate density depending on the device.  This means for mdpi devices, your image will be the appropriate dimensions but for hdpi, xhdpi, and xxhdpi that your image will be much larger than you think and ldpi devices the image will be smaller.

If you don't want the image to scale like that on the Galaxy Nexus then place it in the drawable-xhdpi folder.

Comment: The `-nodpi` might be a better choice for density independent images such as gl textures. Or if he's loading with a `BitmapFactory` he can set the `inScaled` parameter to false.

Comment: Yes, `-nodpi` would indeed be better if he was trying to use his bitmap with OpenGL.  I wasn't sure if that's what he was doing though since if you load ANY bitmap at all over 2048px then you'll get the `OpenGLRenderer` error since the system uses OpenGL for drawing.

Comment: Thanks Jave, I was getting a similar error and the inScaled parameter helped me a lot.